# Counting number of stereo isomer

Tags: stereochemistry

I am having trouble counting the stereo-isomers in this structure:

[image]

There are no chiral carbons. 
The double bonds means there maybe cis-trans geometrical isomerism but the groups are different. So that approach failed.

Answer given is: 4

Comment: The only thing that is different when the groups are different is that cis/trans becomes known as Z/E. Other than that, it is very much still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though all the four groups around double bond are different, the geometrical isomerism is still present. If the groups are not same then the highest priority group on one side of the carbon is determined through CIP sequence rules.

Now if two highest priority groups are on the same side of double bond (syn position), the isomer is called *Z*-isomer. If two highest priority groups are on the opposite side of double bond (anti-position), that isomer is called *E*-isomer.

Here there will be four combinations, i.e (2*Z*,6*Z*); (2*Z*,6*E*); (2*E*,6*Z*); (2*E*, 6*E*). Thus, it gives four possible geometrical isomers.